# Making awarded bounty icons clickable?

Tags: feature-request, bounty

I got an **auto-awarded bounty** on my [answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1936/fondue-without-gruyere-cheese/3099#3099) and got [confused](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/452/what-is-a-bounty-by-community). I tried to click on the +25 icon but to no avail.

I respectfully suggest making awarded bounty icons clickable to explain the bounty system and the bounty clicked on.